# I would like to add line numbers to code samples on my web site. I would like to do this either thru CSS (generated content?) or javascript

Tags: javascript, css

See the code samples on http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/17/taming-advanced-css-selectors/ where the code samples have line numbers. Turning Javascript off (in Firefox) shows these sections without the line numbers. I would like a script that accomplished line numbering.

Comment: Doesn't need to, numbers can be generated using an OL. http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/how_to_style_a_code_listing.asp

Answer (score 3):

Smashing Magazine, like many others, uses a JS library called [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

Another common one is [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).